# Why do these regular expressions execute slowly in Java?

Tags: java, regex, performance

I am trying to use regular expressions to determine what format the user have applied when entering input in a textbox.
The regular expressions are as follows:

```
(\\s?[" + alphabet + "]{9,9})+
```

To determine whether the input is one or more strings of length 9 in a given alphabet, possibly separated by whitespace.

```
(>[\\w\\s]+\\n[" + alphabet + "\\s]+)+
```

To check if the input is in [FASTA format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format)

The regular expressions run terribly slow when matching with `inputString.matches(regexString)`. Why is this?

I figured this may be due to Java storing all potential matches (which I don't need at this point), but adding `?:` in every parenthesis breaks the regex. How should this be done?

Thank you,

Martin

**Edit 1:** I was unable to reproduce this issue - it only happens on one computer. This could suggest something wrong with that particular VM setup.
We need something more robust, and so we will be implementing this differently. I have picked Joel's answer as the right one, since I believe that some special case in Pattern may be the cause.

Comment: How many patterns are you potentially trying to match against each input string?  Are the patterns dynamic or static?

Comment: @Joel There are only these two patterns. They are static. Using String.matches will cause a compilation every time, but even matching against the patterns a single time takes very long (> 10s for about 300 character input)

Comment: can you define "terribly slow"?

Comment: @matt An input string of length 300 will take more than 10 seconds to match on my machine (Intel i7 @ 2.67 GHz)

Comment: If the patterns are static, then use the [Pattern/Matcher answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127570/why-do-these-regular-expressions-execute-slowly-in-java/3127586#3127586 "title") suggested by ddimitrov, i.e., to make multiple calls efficient.  If it is taking 10 seconds for a single matches() call on a 300-character input, then there is something very wrong here.  You may want to try posting a larger section of your code to better clarify the implementation.

Comment: @Martin - The second regular expression may represent a degenerate case for the Pattern class, as I've suggested in a comment for [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127570/why-do-these-regular-expressions-execute-slowly-in-java/3127696#3127696 "title").

Comment: Please post a standalone program that we can run to see this happen!

Comment: side point - you've made sure 'alphabet' can't contain any regex metacharacters, right?

Comment: way, way minor side point -- you can use "\n" in place of "\\n" and "{9}" in place of "{9,9}" -- doesn't help you at all with your problem, but there it is.

Comment: You might want to profile the application on that computer. There is something wrong here and you'd rather know it early before you've spent too much time for nothing based on the wrong assumptions.

Comment: Also it would help if you let us know how do you measure the speed - do you use Unix's 'time' command or do you time it within the program using System.nanoTime()? Do you run the statement only once or do you do it in a loop (what are your min/max/avg/stdev times)? Is this the realistic usage scenario? In Java there are a lot of startup costs and you usually want to discount them when measuring performance (or pick another language).

Comment: @ddimitriov: I simply see a gigantic stack of internal Pattern matching methods. I perform no such timing - the application simply freezes in the matches() call. You are right in that this behavior is strange - however I attribute it to some edge case in a Pattern implementation in one single VM. Since we can just as easily implement this without a regex, I plan to do so. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Martin, that's quite interesting - if it's not a problem I'd be glad to take a look at a short sample demonstrating the issue on that one machine. If you can throw in a thread dump (jstack <pid>) and memory dump (jmap -dump:... <pid>) all the better. I understand that the issue is not major enough for you, but I'm curious :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a number of different regular expression patterns that are being matched against the same input to try to categorize the input, then you are likely to be better off using a lexical analyzer generator like [JFlex](http://www.jflex.de/).

Other Java-based lexical analyzer and parsing tools that are typically used in compiler construction can be found listed [here](http://catalog.compilertools.net/java.html).

Comment: Those are useful tools, thanks! But I only have 2 regexes, and this should be very simple - I think using JFlex and the like would be overkill.

Comment: @Martin - It does sound like JFlex or the like would be more than normally needed in this case.  However, in looking more closely at the regular expressions you are using, it is possible that your case is exposing some degenerate case in how the Pattern class compiles its analyzer.  It may be worth trying JFlex just to see if it can produce a tighter analyzer for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

string.matches() compile the regex every time you do it. Instead, look at the Pattern/Matcher classes, which allow you to cache precompiled regexes.

Another thing is to use non-capturing regex groups if you don't need the result of the matching.

Comment: I only call matches() once, so that should not be a problem. The regexes perform well with small input, but horrendously slowly with input of more that, say, 200 characters.
I was unable to get non-capturing groups to work - can you give an example?

Comment: Switching to non-capturing groups won't give you a factor of 1000 improvement. Still, this is how you do it -  put ?: after the opening parenthesis - example: (?:\\s?[" + alphabet + "]{9,9})+

Answer (score 0):

this might not explain your particular problem. but once I dived into JDK's regex implementation, and I was surprised at how *unsophisticated* it is. it doesn't really build a state machine that advances at each input char. I assume they have their reasons.

in your case, it is so easy to write a parse by yourself, by hand. people fear to do that, it seems "dumb" to manually code these tiny steps, and people think established libraries must be doing some splendid tricks to outperform home grown solutions. that's not true. in many cases, our needs are rather simple, and it is simpler and faster to DIY.

Comment: The Pattern.compile() method does build state machine of the descendends of Pattern.Node class. Do you mean that it builds a NFA automaton as opposed to DFA? That is the design used by most feature-rich regex engines, trading speed for features. Here is an article explaining this and suggesting alternative: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/03/27/faster-java-regex-package